# What application is asking for a password change?

Tags: passwords

A friend of mine received this pop up on his Mac. It does not look like a typical password reminder that a MDM would show.

I cannot figure out what service is asking for this password change, and would like to see what I can use to figure it out.

The MacBook Pro in question is running 10.11.6.

[image]

Comment: Did you check running processes ?  however this is not related to security, should be posted on Superuser site.

Comment: My friend stated that he saw it while running his terminal and after force quitting it. Sorry if this is the wrong place to post, but given the security element, and different exposure pentesters across this forum I thought I would get a better hit.

Comment: Here we can only guess and assume what it is. Even go as far as tin foil hat territory and tell you it could be a virus mimicking a real notification window. This is because from a picture alone with have no understanding of the processes and overall stack. So I agree this may be better question for Superuser.